# How do I click the li tag inside ul with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
<div class="hdetSelect right moreRooms" style="">
<select class="bookedRoom_1 perSelector xsmall number-room-booked_fbc1336de4c882dd" ref="1" id="selectRoomBooked_1" style="display: none;">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   </select>
<div class="nsSelect-container search-num-selector left">
   <input class="nsSelect-input bookedRoom_1 perSelector xsmall number-room-booked_fbc1336de4c882dd" type="text" style="display: inline-block;">
   <div class="nsSelect-opt-container search-num-selector left rounded5 hide" style="top: 696.8px; left: 875px; display: none;">
   <ul>
   <li class="clear" style="display: block; width: 27px;">
   <a href="#" ref="0" class="">0</a>
   </li>
   <li style="display: block; width: 27px;">
   <a href="#" ref="1" class="active">1</a>
   </li></ul>
   <a class="nsSelect-close">Cancel</a></div></div>
  <span class="dRoom">Room</span> 
</div>
```

I'm trying to click an li inside a ul using XPath or `cssSelector`, but I always get the error "no such element: Unable to locate".

Here's what I'm trying with:

With JavaScript executor with `cssSelector`:

```
WebElement room_num = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.room-list-item:nth-child(1)> div:nth-child(1)> div:nth-child(4)> div:nth-child(2)> div:nth-child(2)> ul:nth-child(1)> li:nth-child(2)>a"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",room_num);
```

With XPath :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='room-list']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
```

I want to select/click(UI) li with innerHTML 1 ,but nothing seems to work. I'm running out of ideas so please do leave feedback or maybe solution.

Comment: First i would suggest you to use the chrome dev tools where you can rightclick on an element and copy-> xpath to use the value for your path

Comment: yes, my xpath selector it was copied from chrome dev tools.

Comment: Than the only reason i can think of is that the dom is generated after you try to access the element, for that i have to need more details of what technologies are involved e.t.c

Comment: the technologie how you do the html. is the html there already or are you using things like angularjs or similar client render engines

Comment: oh ok, the technlogy is modernizr 2.6.2, jquery 1.7.2, jquery UI 1.8.18( i think web dev had modified the original jquery to create custom ui)

Comment: so did you try to make a delay before you try to access the element, lets say 5-10 sec?

Comment: yes, of course i do

Comment: Think you should use the Select class of Selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found solution from [link](http://learn-automation.com/solve-elementnotvisibleexception-in-selenium-webdriver/)

this is part of my code, how to solve element not visible exception when click li

```
 WebElement room_select1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[2]"));
(( JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", room_select1);
int li_size=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@ref='1']")).size();
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@ref='1']")).get(li_size-1).click();
```